# What is the layout used by Rails guides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Anyone knows if there are any framework or layout that use the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and the [RefineryCMS guides](http://refinerycms.com/guides)? Both of then have a similar interface and I want to make my own guide with the same view.

Comment: Do you mean "are used by the Rails Guides..."? The HTML seems simple, so is your question if there is a framework behind that generates the guides?

Comment: Yes, both webs have the same interfaces, so my question if there is a framework behind.

Comment: You can look on your own. Have a look at your local rails gems, especially `railties`. There is included a directory `guides`, where you may generate the rails guides for yourself (locally). The relevant file here is `railties-<version>/guides/rails_guides/generator.rb`. For me, it looks as if there is a clever usage of some rails parts (rendering), but mostly using textile (only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RailsGuides is all open source. You can see the docrails repository here:
https://github.com/lifo/docrails/tree/master/railties/guides/rails_guides

There you can find the css, javascript, and generator code they use.